# diagnosing errors using SendGrid and cURL

Tags: curl, sendgrid

New to SendGrid, but our admin has created a sub-account for my group to start working with.  I've logged in to the dashboard, and working through the intro exercise to try to send a sample email via cURL (Setup Guide / Integrate / WebAPI / cURL).  The steps listed are:

1. Make sure you have access to the command line (they provide a link to download cURL, but it was already on my machine)
2. Create an API key - done
3. Create an environment variable - done
4. Run the code - here's where I'm getting problems.

The code provided by Twilio is:

```
curl --request POST   --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send   --header "Authorization: Bearer %SENDGRID_API_KEY%"   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "test@example.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "test@example.com"},"subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with cURL"}]}'
```

I took their sample code, modified the "test@example.com" to put in valid email addresses, and changed the environment variable from "$SENDGRID_API_KEY" to "%SENDGRID_API_KEY%" since this is being run on Windows.

When I run it, I get:

```
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2: 
[{to:
^
```

The curl command has "--header 'Content-Type: application/json'", so I'm unsure why that comes out on the error message.  Then there's the "Could not resolve host: application" and "bad range specification in URL" messages.

I've tried several variations, like removing the '--url https://..." and just appending the URL to the end of the command:

```
curl --request POST   --header "Authorization: Bearer %SENDGRID_API_KEY%"   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "test@example.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "test@example.com"},"subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with cURL"}]}'  https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send
```

Doing that clears the "Content-Type should be application/json" message, but the other two remain:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application  
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2:
```

Those errors appear to be generated by curl itself, but I'm not having much luck resolving them.  There was one post on github from 2020 listing a bug when a URL included '[' or ']' characters, but that's not the case here.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - that resulted in the following:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: @mc301 Looks like this Sendgrid example is from their "Integrate using our Web API or SMTP Relay" [Email API setup](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/curl). Does pasting in the back slash "\" from the examples on the page make a difference? It seems like something is up with curl being able to cURL parsing your options. Also, have you switched to double quotes vs single quotes in the cURL command?

Comment: @Christine - I have tried switching b/t double and single quotes, with the results listed in my reply to Giacomo1968.  I also tried the backslash, both as a single "\" and a "\\" just in case there was something weird with the parsing, but that did not resolve the issue either.